# Why isn't my Docker container running my cron script, but it does when I do service cron restart?

Tags: docker, cron

Cron isn't a running process when I go into my container, but when go into the container and  bash `service cron restart` it starts running, I can't figure out why this isn't working with the `service cron restart` but not without it?

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \ 
    cron \
    nano \
    psmisc \
    wget

COPY hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod +x /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

my hello-cron script

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" > /usr/src/helloworldcron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Is the crond outside or inside the container? I wouldn't put it inside because it requires your container to run all the time and the container focus on cron instead of its job. Instead, you should run the container everytime the task runs and put the scheduling outside of the container. The approach to put scheudling inside a container is completely against the idea of containers. Putting it on AWS, it will waste resources and cost money without doing anything. Even Kubernetes has its own scheduling afaik.

Comment: @DanielW. I am brand new to Docker so it seems as though I've made a misstep by sticking it in the container within my DO server...? How would one run it from outside the container? Any link to a resource would be great thanks!

Comment: Go to your hosts crontab/scheduler (crond, but also systemd would work) and put the line in there like `docker run ...`. Also putting `* * * * *` means it runs every minute. Maybe you are not looking for a job at all but for streamed processing.

Comment: Oh, ok I think I understand. So basically in the server, which contains the docker containers, I just spin up a container based on the cron task. This container is already running my code. Then, when finished running the code I somehow call to stop the container and then remove it? Thinking about this, the concern I have is how to communicate between the process I want to run finishing and shutting down the container. Am I grapsing this correctly?

Comment: [Containers are recommended to have only 1 focused active process](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) and when it's done, the container stops automatically. When you put crond + your job into the container, there are 2 processes that have focus. You can check if a container is still running and if it doesn't, restart it. You can even configure containers to [automatically restart when they're done](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) .

Comment: Aha, interesting. The more I dig into it the more I'm realizing containers aren't the solution I'm seeking. Considering that it's a nodejs app that needs to run through a VPN once a day for about 4 hours. I think I'm overoptimizing and a VPS at $20/mo should work just fine for me :) Thanks for your help, Daniel!

Comment: It's a complex topic and there are many possibilities. I wonder why in this scenario you need a cronjob? Start a container, let it run for four hours, container stops. What do you need scheduling for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219836/discussion-between-mpc75-and-daniel-w).